# Is $[L : K] = 2$, $f \in K[x]$ irreducible, then $\operatorname{deg}(f) \le 2$ valid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Is it true that in every field extension of degree two, every irreducible polynomials has a degree smaller than two? And if so, how can I proof this?

Answer (score 4):

No take $K = \Bbb{Q}$ and $L = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ but $f(x) = x^4 - 2 \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you meant to ask if all elements of $L$ have a minimal polynomial of degree at most 2? If that's what you meant, then suppose $\alpha\in L$. Then $K\subseteq K(\alpha) \subseteq L$. Then, by the tower law,
$$ 2 = [L : K] = [L : K(\alpha)][K(\alpha) : K].$$
Hence, $K(\alpha)$ must be $L$ or $K$. If $\alpha\in K$, then its minimal polynomial over $K$ is $x-\alpha$. Otherwise $L = K(\alpha)$, and then the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is the degree of the extension $[K(\alpha):K] = [L:K] = 2$.

Comment: yes, thats what I meant. But why is the degree of the minimal polynomial equals to the degree of the extension?

Comment: That only works when you have a field generated by a single element. Recall that the degree of $K(\alpha)/K$ is the dimension of $K(\alpha)$ as a $K$-vector space. Suppose $m(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0\in K[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Then $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots, \alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a $K$-basis. Can you see why this is a basis? Remember that $K(\alpha) = K[\alpha]$, so every element of the field looks like a $K$ polynomial of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A general example would be $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ where $\alpha=\sqrt[n]{2}$
and the polynomial $p(x)=x^{m}-3$ .

This is a field extension of degree $n$ and an irreducible polynomial
of degree $m$.